# Add datepicker after retrieving document by ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, datepicker

I have been adding datepicker functionality to some textfield with success results, but when I try to apply it to a document that has been loaded into a div it fails.

I load the document with

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="FAjax('form_ajustes_salida.php','ok4','','post');">Ajustes salida</a>
```

where FAjax is

```
function FAjax(url, capa, valores, metodo){

    var ajax=creaAjax();
    if (metodo.toUpperCase()=='POST'){
        ajax.open('POST', url, true);
        ajax.onreadystatechange =function(){
            procesaAjax(ajax,capa);
            }
        ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        ajax.send(valores);
        return;
    }
    if (metodo.toUpperCase()=='GET'){
        ajax.open('GET', url, true);
        ajax.onreadystatechange =function(){
            procesaAjax(ajax,capa);
            }
        ajax.setRequestHeader('Content-Type','application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        ajax.send(null);
        return;
    }

    }
```

I tried to apply datepicker from the main document and the loaded document, with no results.

Could you please help me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually what such datepicker plugins do is like, it will look for the input element in the `DOM` and then bind events to it to show the custom picker.

In your case, the element to which the datepicker is applied is loaded to `DOM` at a later time using `AJAX` and javascript. So the datepicker can be applied only after the input element is added to the `DOM`.

If `procesaAjax(ajax,capa);` is supposed to add the response HTML to the `DOM` , then you can just call date-picker initialization after that.

```
procesaAjax(ajax,capa);
$('input#myinput').datePicker();
```

Comment: i think it wont work, cause procesAjax is async to javascript execution so before DOM load it would call date picker

Answer (score 0):

That's because normally you set the datepicker inside:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".date").datepicker({
       format : "dd-mm-yyyy"
    });
});
```

This will only be applied to preexisting fields so that when the browser compiles the page it sets the date picker.

If you're loading the page with ajax then after you load the div invoke:

```
    $(".date").datepicker({
       format : "dd-mm-yyyy"
    });
```

And it should work.

Best regards